# Kafka Ignite sink connector remote node data transfer

Tags: caching, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, ignite, gridgain

I am trying to send data from Kafka to Ignite using Ignite Sink Connector. I have done little experiments :

1. When I am running Kafka and Ignite on same machine locally with connector, I am able to send the data. - In this case I have provided xml configuration file for ignite in connector.properties which includes CacheName and Discovery property.
2. When I am trying to run them on remote node and connector on Kafka server's node it is unable to push the data even if I change IP in discovery property. - In this case I am running ignite with xml configuration on other node with that node's ip via terminal shell script.
3. When I am running kafka and ignite on remote node's but connector on ignite side, it's able to pull from kafka and push into cache.

I am very new to Ignite. Please help me out with these doubts.
I am using same xml configuration file which comes with ignite setup called example-cache.xml

Why is it so?
Ideally, On which side worker and connector should run , Kafka or Ignite ? If I want to make them at kafka server only? What changes that I need to do?
Have I mistaken something to configure in xml configuration? If Yes, what should be the configurations that I should made in my ignite server xml file and in xml file which I pass in connector?

Comment: I guess it's just some configuration issue. Can you please prepare the archive with your reproducer?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I could make connections established. As you said, this was discovery configuration bothering in connection establishment